# Should the Kubernetes api server be accesible as https://kubernetes:443 from any pod in the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

According to the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/),

> The kubernetes service (in all namespaces) is configured with a virtual IP address that is redirected (via kube-proxy) to the HTTPS endpoint on the apiserver.

For some reason I can't access `kubernetes` from a non-`default` namespace, unless I manually create the service there (or use `kubernetes.default`). Looking at the [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.9/pkg/master/controller.go#L269) I see the `kubernetes` service is created in namespace `default`, is it also available in other namespaces? If so, how is that accomplished? How might I debug it?

I've been finding it difficult to Google this, since "kubernetes service" is not really a great search keyword.

For the record, I'm using GKE.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @aerokite I'm running Zeppelin from https://github.com/banzaicloud/banzai-charts/tree/master/stable/zeppelin, and it hard-codes the master as k8s://https://kubernetes:443 for Spark submission. This works if Zeppelin is in `default` and can be changed from the UI, but I was wondering if it was expected to work as-is in other namespaces, or if it should be changed. Also, the Kubernetes documentation seems inconsistent with the behavior I observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service `kubernetes` is only available in Namespace `default`.

If you want to access API server using this service, you need to use `kubernetes.default`

> Services are assigned a DNS A record for a name of the form
>
> ```
>             my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
> ```
>
> This resolves to the cluster IP of the Service.

That means, you need to use `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`

You can skip `svc.cluster.local`.

So to access a `kubernetes` Service, you need to provide `kubernetes.default`.

If you want to access from default namespace, you can skip namespace part.

See details in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services).

Also,

> When you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is automatically assigned the **default** service account in the same namespace.

You can access the API from inside a pod using automatically mounted service account credentials, as described in [Accessing the Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod).

Comment: That's what I figured, wanted to be sure since it seems to be at odds with the documentation which talks about "the kubernetes service (in all namespaces)"